# Why don't you need execute permissions in the jars in your classpath

Tags: java, jvm

I've always thought you need execute permissions set in the jars that are in the classpath of your java program. But I found out today that in fact all you need is read permissions. I was a bit surprised at first glance, but I think it makes sense since the JVM only needs to read class files (jvm bytecode) and actually interpret/compile that into OS runnable bytecode. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Even if .jar files contained native executables (they don't), they still wouldn't need execute permissions because they're simply zip archives. Some other program (such as the java VM) needs to extract the contents first to do anything with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the jars aren't being executed.

the java executable (or javaw) is what needs the execute bit.  it is simply reading other files (.jar or .class).

Comment: +1; I'd also add that this is the same for any interpreted language -- you don't need execute permissions on `myprogram.py` to run `python myprgoram.py`. The `python` executable just needs to be able to read the program file.